# Read another file as input in vba

Tags: vba, excel, input

I have this macro in a excel file:

```
Sub ore()
Sheets(1).Select
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
drow = 2
For r = 2 To LR
  ore = Cells(r, 4)
  nome = Cells(r, 2)
  totore = totore + ore
  n = n + 1
  If ore <> 8 Then
    Rows(r).Copy Sheets("log").Cells(drow, 1)
    drow = drow + 1
  End If
  If n = 5 Then
'    Stop
    If totore <> 40 Then
      Sheets("log").Cells(drow - 1, 5) = totore
    End If
    n = 0: totore = 0
  End If
Next
 Sheets("log").Select
End Sub
```

That starts when i click a button. This file is called "example.xlsm". I want take this macro and write it in another file called "readfile.xlsm" and call as an input to the "example.xlsm" file. So I need to read the data of "example.xlsm" file in summary. How can I do this? I tried to write

`Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.xlsm"`

but it doesn't work. Thanks

EDIT:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim path As String
    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Dim openWs As Worksheet

    path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.xlsm"

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With openWs
        '~~> Rest of your code here
        Sheets(1).Select
        LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        drow = 2
        For r = 2 To LR
          ore = Cells(r, 4)
          nome = Cells(r, 2)
          totore = totore + ore
          n = n + 1
          If ore <> 8 Then
            Rows(r).Copy Sheets("log").Cells(drow, 1)
            drow = drow + 1
          End If
          If n = 5 Then
        '    Stop
            If totore <> 40 Then
              Sheets("log").Cells(drow - 1, 5) = totore
            End If
            n = 0: totore = 0
          End If
        Next
         Sheets("log").Select
        End With

    'openWb.Close (True)
End Sub
```

This doesn't work either.

Comment: When I meant `rest of the code`, I didn't mean that you copy paste the original code and not make any changes to it :p

Comment: Also where is `Sheets("log")`? in which workbook?

Comment: ahah ok..well.. cutting `Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")` and change `With openWs` in `With openWb` it works.. but the sheet log i would that open in `readflie` instead `example`.. can be possible?

Comment: Yes then you will have to declare those objects as well. One moment updating my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create your object and then work with them. See this example. This code goes in `readfile.xlsm`

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim path As String
    Dim openWb As Workbook
    Dim openWs As Worksheet

    path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.xlsm"

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With openWs
        '~~> Rest of your code here
    End With

    'openWb.Close (True)
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

When I meant `rest of the code`, I didn't mean that you copy paste the original code and not make any changes to it :p Also another important tip: Use `Option Explicit` I see lot of undeclared variables. I have declared all of them to `Long` Change as applicable

**Try this (Untested)**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim path As String
    Dim openWb As Workbook, thiswb As Workbook
    Dim openWs As Worksheet, Logws As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long, dRow As Long, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim ore As Long, nome As Long, totore As Long

    path = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\example.xlsm"

    Set thiswb = ThisWorkbook

    Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set Logws = openWb.Sheets.Add

    '~~> Create Log Sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    openWb.Sheets("log").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0

    Logws.Name = "log"

    With openWs
        '~~> Rest of your code here
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        dRow = 2

        For r = 2 To LR
            ore = .Cells(r, 4).Value
            'nome = .Cells(r, 2).Value '<~~ Why do we need this?
            totore = totore + ore

            n = n + 1

            If ore <> 8 Then
                .Rows(r).Copy Logws.Cells(dRow, 1)
                dRow = dRow + 1
            End If

            If n = 5 Then
                If totore <> 40 Then
                    Logws.Cells(dRow - 1, 5) = totore
                End If
                n = 0: totore = 0
            End If
        Next
    End With
    'openWb.Close (True)
End Sub
```

Comment: i've tryied but i'm not sure because i get an error. Look at my edit

Comment: couple of questions.. `1` Where are you running the above code from? I mean which file? `2` Where is the Log sheet?

Comment: the above code is inside a module in the `readfile.xlsm` and the log sheet, i want display it in example.xls file but actually it creates in `readfile.xlsm`

Comment: That is because you mentioned in the comment below your question that the log file is in `readfile` or maybe i understood? Change `Set thisws = thiswb.Sheets("log")` to `Set thisws = openWb.Sheets("log")` and copy it after `Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet1")` Now try it

Comment: That means you don't have the "log" sheet in the that file. Are you sure the sheet exists?

Comment: maybe i was not clear.. That sheet `log` it will create when i click the button.. at the beginning the sheet doesn't exist. It must be created after all. Understand now?

Comment: Ehi it works but it still open the other file.. I mean, it creates what i want but it also open the other file i think because there is : `Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)` that open the file. But i'm not sure.. Is it possible only read it?

Comment: i think i can't in the chat today because i'm at work and here the chat page is inaccessible. :/ .anyway, the problem is the file that i don't want open. Everything must be on the `readfile.xlsm` file. I already create a "log" sheet in the `readfile.xlsm` so don't need to create it. I just want read the datas from the example file and put the macro's results in the "log" sheet of `readfile.xlsm` without open `example.xlsm`

Comment: kool. next question. What do you have in `Example.xlsm`? Data to generate for the log sheet which is in `readfile.xlsm` Correct? Now in my code did you see the last line which says `openWb.Close (True)`. Uncomment that and change it to `openWb.Close (False)` This will ensure that the file is closed after the complete operation

Comment: have i to remove the inverted comma?

Comment: Only last thing, is possible to go directly in the "log" sheet after click button with macro? in my first code i wrote : `Sheet("Log").Select` but now i get runtime error 1004 if i write it.

Comment: `thiswb.Sheet("Log").Activate`. Put this right after `openWb.Close (False)`